# Error Angular component no detectado en la importación

Tags: angular, ngroute

Este es mi archivo de rutas y cuando hago la importación de heroe, no me lo detecta, pero si comento la linea `{ path: 'heroe', component: HeroeComponent }` todo funciona bien.

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './Components/heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroeComponent } from './Components/heroe/heroe.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './Components/about/about.component';

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent },
    { path: 'heroe', component: HeroeComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(APP_ROUTES)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RoutingModule {}
// export const app_routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

El stacktrace del error es el siguiente:
[image: error]

Comment: Se que es algo sencillo pero podrias revisar esta linea : import { HeroeComponent } from './Components/heroe/heroe.component';
si en realidad se encuentra en ese path verificar que este bien escrito

Comment: La ruta la genera angular, entonces creo que si esta bien escrita.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas Gracias @JuankGlezz, Al parecer el error es algo, entre el alias y el componente real, no se exactamente como explicarlo, pero al importar el componente, al archivo de rutas, este genera dos archivos con el mismo nombre, y se debe elegir el componente como tal y no el alias.

Ejemplo:[image: Error al elegir el componente]